# VSTO C# MailItem.Attachments.Add() Crashes

Tags: c#, vsto, attachment, mailitem

I have following code

```
public void SendAttachmentsClick()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMailItem = HostAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    oMailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

    // //returns strings representing paths to documents I want to attach
    List<string> paths = GetAttachmentsPaths(); 
    if (paths.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string itemPath in paths)
        {
            oMailItem.Attachments.Add(itemPath);
        }

        if (oMailItem.Attachments.Count > 0)
        {
            oMailItem.Display(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**CALL 1:** Calling `SendAttachmentsClick()` for the 1st time opens new email and attaches all attachments to it properly.

**CALL 2:** If I click Cancel in this new email message and then call `SendAttachmentsClick()` again, I can trace execution up until call to `oMailItemAttachments.Add(itemPath)` above (I have break points in this code).  However, once this line is called for the very first attachments in the 2nd call, the whole VSTO/outlook just crashes.  I added try...catch to try to catch exception but it is never entered so I don't know what the error is.

**UPDATE1:**
After reading an article by Eugene Astafiev at https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/10/how-to-add-attachment-to-e-mail-message/?thank=you&t=1467071796#comment-413803, I modified my code above to release com objects and now it looks like this but the problem still persists

```
public void SendAttachmentsClick()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMailItem = HostAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    oMailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
    Selection olSelection = HostAddIn.ActiveExplorer.Selection;

    // //returns strings representing paths to documents I want to attach
    List<string> paths = GetAttachmentsPaths(); 
    if (paths.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachments mailAttachments = oMailItem.Attachments;
            foreach (string itemPath in paths)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment newAttachment = mailAttachments.Add(itemPath); 
                oMailItem.Save(); 
                if (newAttachment != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newAttachment);
            }

            if (oMailItem.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                oMailItem.Display(false);
            }

            if (mailAttachments != null) 
               Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailAttachments); 
            if (oMailItem.Attachments != null) 
               Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oMailItem.Attachments);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (oMailItem != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oMailItem);
                oMailItem = null;
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(olSelection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how your GetAttachmentsPaths() is getting the paths. Are the files existent on your local machine or you are downloading them from somewhere? If you are downloading them from somewhere, could it be that your cancel logic is deleting the downloads?

Comment: I believing you are right.  What do you suggest?   Much appreciated

Comment: I would move downloaded files to another temporary directory, process them from there, then delete the temp directory.  I posted partial solution below.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per suggested, I would do it something like this.  You dont have to save your mail item like you do above.  Note that I have not provided you the logic for your GetAttachmentsPaths method as I dont know how you do that but it looks to me that you are downloading the files from somewhere first and you confirmed that.  I did however provide with very good instructions how to write this method and return paths of downloaded files.  Hope that helps.

```
public async void SendAttachmentByMailClick()
{
    // delete temp directory if it exists, then create brand new one each time
    var tempFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyTempFolder");
    if (Directory.Exists(tempFolder)) 
    { 
        Directory.Delete(tempFolder, true); 
    }
    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);

    // get your list asynchronously
    List<string> paths = null; 
    try  
    {
        // I am doing this asynchronously but awaiting until I get files.  I
        // would use a TaskCompletionSource (google for it) and once you
        // receive each file, store it's path in a List<string> object.
        // Check that the List<string> Count is equal to passed in
        // selection.Count and when it is, pass the list to TrySetResult()
        // of TaskCompletionSource.  Wrap that in try...catch and in catch
        // block pass the exception to TrySetException method of 
        // TaskCompletionSource.  This method should await and return
        // Task object of TaskCompletionSource which will then contain the
        // list of paths to your downloaded files.  Then you move one with 
        // logic below to copy them to temp location and attach them from 
        // there.
        paths = await GetAttachmentsPaths(MyAddIn.ActiveExplorer.Selection);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // handle exceptions 
        return;
    }

    // create new message
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMailItem = MyAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem); 

    if (paths != null && paths.Count > 0)
    {
        var attachmentFileName = String.Empty; 
        try
        {
            // if list has downloaded files, copy them to tempFolder
            List<string> copiedPaths = GetCopiedPaths(tempFolder, paths);

            if (copiedPaths.Count > 0)
            {
                // then attach each from that location
                foreach (var itemPath in copiedPaths)
                {
                    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(itemPath);
                    if (fInfo.Exists)
                    {
                        attachmentFileName = fInfo.Name; 
                        oMailItem.Attachments.Add(itemPath, OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, fInfo.Name);
                    }
                    // delete file once attached to clean up
                    fInfo.Delete();
                }
            }

            if (oMailItem.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                oMailItem.Display(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exceptions
        }
        finally
        {
            // delete temporary folder once done
            if (Directory.Exists(tempFolder)) 
            { 
                Directory.Delete(tempFolder, true); 
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks again!  This was the reason why I had issues.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting from releasing all underlying COM objects instantly in the code. For that you need to use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. And then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx) article.

For example, I have noticed the following chain of property and method calls:

```
  foreach (string itemPath in paths)
    {
        oMailItem.Attachments.Add(itemPath);
    }
```

The `Attachments` property of the `MailItem` class returns an instance of the correspondiong class from the OOM. And it should be released after.

The `Add` method of the `Attachments` class returns an [Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863918.aspx) object that represents the new attachment. So, it should be released too.

Comment: Thanks Eugene.  I found your blog yesterday (@ https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/10/how-to-add-attachment-to-e-mail-message/?thank=you&t=1467071796#comment-413803) and added logic to call ReleaseComObject.  Please see UPDATE1 above.  The problem still persists though.

Comment: I still see lines of code where you don't release underlying COM objects. For example: if (oMailItem.Attachments.Count > 0)

Comment: I added the line (please see the updated code block above).  Still no effect.  Issue still exists.  I also noticed that if the crash happens, neither my catch nor finally block will execute.